# Returning 404 when param not matches using react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm using react-router v4.1 and i would like to use a global 404 page for any unmatched param from a given array of numbers [1-50]

`<Route path='/:id'component={App}>`

In this exemple if `id` > 50 or < 1 then a `404 page` should be rendered and if `id` is inside this interval render `App`

In this exemple any id will render App

Comment: Have you tried anything to achieve this ?

Comment: no, i'm new in react and i have no idea how to do this

Comment: For instance, have you read the documentation?

Comment: yes, i found [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/no-match) but this exemple is not uing param like `:[something]`

Comment: i found this guy having a similar question, but is too old and i dont found how to do this. [link](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/2457)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a catch-all route to catch any paths that don't resolve:

```
<Route path="*" component={NoMatch}/>
```

Where `NoMatch` would be a 404 component.

Comment: in this exemple all paths will return `NoMatch`? what i need to do is return `App` when `:id` is in the interval of 1-50 otherwise return `NoMatch`

Comment: Okay sorry, misunderstood the question. Putting this as the last route will catch all undefined paths. For your case though, in the `App` component, you should check the id and if it is > 50 or < 1 then you manually route to a 404 component.

Comment: it works. But I was looking for some way to do this through some prop of the react-router like some matcher 

`const itens = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

<Route path='/:id' match{itens} component={App}> `